# DMARC compliance for AWS SES bounce emails sent with SendBounce

Tags: amazon-ses, spf, dkim, email-bounces, dmarc

AWS SES has an API for programmatically sending a bounce email in reply to a received email—[`SendBounce`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendBounce.html). However, emails sent through `SendBounce`—unlike "normal" emails sent through [`SendEmail`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html)—only contain a `DKIM-Signature` for `amazonses.com`. Since bounced emails use `MAIL FROM: <>`, both of these result in SPF and DKIM alignment failure, and thus DMARC failure.

With this, is it even possible to achieve DMARC compliance for emails sent with `SendBounce`? And is there a good reason why SES does not include a DKIM signature with the `From:` domain for `SendBounce` emails?

#### Example

- SES email domain: `email.com`
- MAIL FROM domain for `email.com`: `from.email.com`
- DMARC record (`_dmarc.email.com`): `v=DMARC1; p=quarantine`

  - Note: Because `adkim` and `aspf` tags are omitted, the DMARC conducts alignment for DKIM and SPF in "relaxed" mode.

A sample email sent with `SendEmail` has the following:

- `From:` header: `normal@email.com`
- `HELO` identity: `a27-123.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com`
- `MAIL FROM`: `<01010181add736ef-0f477553-2014-4704-b7ee-a030525d7a66-000000@from.email.com>`

  - `from.email.com` is a subdomain of `email.com`, which achieves [*relaxed* SPF alignment](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7489#section-3.1).
- `DKIM-Signature: d=amazonses.com`
- `DKIM-Signature: d=email.com`

  - `email.com` is exactly `email.com`, which achieves [*strict* DKIM alignment](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7489#section-3.1).

However, an email sent via `SendBounce` has:

- `From:` header: `mailer-daemon@email.com`
- `HELO` identity: `a27-9.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com`
- `MAIL FROM`: `<>` (empty, [as expected for a bounce message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message))
- `DKIM-Signature: d=amazonses.com`

Note that for the bounce email, neither the `HELO` identity nor any of the DKIM signature domains match the `From:` domain of `email.com`. Hence, DMARC fails.

#### Possible workaround (hack)

Given these limitations of bounce messages sent with `SendBounce`, one workaround which preserves DMARC (with a `p=reject` or `p=quarantine` policy) for normal emails but disables it for bounce emails is to designate a subdomain of `email.com` with DMARC explicitly disabled.

For example, set `_dmarc.bounce.email.com` to `v=DMARC1; p=none`, and use `mailer-daemon@bounce.email.com` as the `From:` address of `SendBounce`. This allows `SendBounce` emails to not end up in spam or dropped outright (per DMARC) but hardly seems like an ideal solution.

Comment: Mxxk, did you ever log this with AWS, if so what was the outcome?
We have some customers that demand DMARC quarantine so setting this back to none falls foul of that policy.
Whereas if we leave it at quarantine and don't use the workaround then alignment fails as you've correctly noted and emails can equally fail.
This needs a proper fix from AWS to allow sending a MAIL FROM attribute with the SendBounce action.
PS, thank you for documenting this, it immediately lead me to the problem.

Comment: @n00borama no I actually haven't, but agree with you that this is probably a good thing to do. Frankly, posting it here on StackOverflow might not have been the best outlet, but at least I wanted to check if anyone else experienced this. If I understand correctly, you were able to see the same behavior in this post with emails sent via `SendBounce`?

Comment: Correct, we see emails coming in and getting bounced by mimecast that look like this:
`Authentication-Resultsrelay.mimecast.com; dkim=pass header.d=amazonses.com header.s=224i4yxa5dv7c2xz3womw6peuasteono header.b=YV+6T2AQ; dmarc=fail reason="SPF not aligned (relaxed), DKIM not aligned (relaxed)" header.from=our.domain.com (policy=quarantine); spf=pass (relay.mimecast.com: domain of a14-96.smtp-out.amazonses.com designates 54.240.14.96 as permitted sender) smtp.helo=a14-96.smtp-out.amazonses.com`

It's missing `smtp.mailfrom` which would've put it into alignment.

I logged it to AWS.

Comment: @n00borama thanks for taking the initiative to report this to AWS. Though, instead of emphasizing in the ticket that bounce emails are missing `smtp.mailfrom`, you might want to emphasize that bounce emails are missing the DKIM signature with the `d=email.com` domain. According to RFC 1123 (https://serverfault.com/a/151987) bounce emails _intentionally_ use the empty email address `<>` as the SMTP FROM to prevent a possible bounce loop. Based on this, it seems that bounce emails cannot possible have SPF alignment, and the _only_ way a bounce email can pass DMARC is through DKIM alignment.

Comment: (On a separate note, I would like confirmation from someone knowledgeable in this space regarding the point "the only way a bounce email can pass DMARC is through DKIM alignment" since it has more general implications than AWS SES.)

Comment: Actually, according to https://www.validity.com/blog/how-to-authenticate-your-bounce-messages-with-dmarc/, since there is no MAIL FROM on bounce messages, the SPF alignment check can be carried out against SMTP EHLO/HELO. This doesn't help, because as your case shows, `smtp.helo=a14-96.smtp-out.amazonses.com`, and to SPF align you would need to set the `From` header to `...@a14-96.smtp-out.amazonses.com`, which SES won't allow. So it sounds like DKIM alignment is the only way.

Comment: Yes, we also read that MAIL FROM wasn't possible on bounces. I've put that to AWS and they've escalated to the SES team to give me a configuration that would pass DMARC with proper alignment.
It's possible that we'd have to use 'bounce@amazonses.com' as the bounce sender if that's even possible. Not ideal from a 'my domain' point of view but if it passes DMARC it's more agreeable to most mail admins.

Comment: Had a reply from AWS that amounts to 'use the subdomain with p=none workaround'.
They've got this logged as an internal enhancement but can't comment on a time to get it implemented.

Comment: Thanks for following up with the AWS response! Good to know.